# EventTriggerBehavior Tapped not firing

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light, behavior

I'm using MVVM-light approach for Pushpins on my Map.
I have bound the Tapped Event to a Command in my ViewModel.
However the event is not triggered.
All the other commands and properties bind perfectly.
I have also tried as an example to use a regular event, but it's also not firing.

My Command in my VM

```
private RelayCommand<Check> _showDetailCheckCommand;
public RelayCommand<Check> ShowDetailCheckCommand
{
    get
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Binded");
        return _showDetailCheckCommand ?? (_showDetailCheckCommand = new RelayCommand<Check>((c) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Action!");
        }));

    }
}
```

In  my XAML

```
<Page
    x:Name="pageRoot" 
...


<Maps:MapControl x:Name="Map" IsEnabled="False" Margin="0,8,0,8" MapServiceToken="******" LandmarksVisible="False" PedestrianFeaturesVisible="False" TrafficFlowVisible="True"  ZoomLevel="16">
    <!-- Incidents -->
    <Maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding checks}">
        <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Tag="{Binding}" Source="{Binding image_path}" Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding geodata, Converter={StaticResource RoadsmartCoordinatesToGeoPointConverter}}" Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint=".5,.5" >
                    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowDetailCheckCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"  />
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </Maps:MapItemsControl>
</Maps:MapControl>
```

My output log does say:
'Binded'
But when I click on the image on the map the 'Action' is not executed.

Comment: Does it fire from that event at all? You sure it's "Tapped" you want and not like Clicked, or MouseLeftButtonDown etc? Is this for RT? I mean at first glance it looks legit.

Comment: Windows Universal. The event name is Tapped there is no Clicked Event on the Image control. The event is not fired when handling it in the code behind too

Comment: Do you need the DataContext in `DataContext.ShowDetailCheckCommand`? Depends how the page's DataContext is set

Comment: Yes I do need it. My Datacontext is not my code behind but a ViewModel. I get Binding Error when not setting the Datacontext in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid of me.
I had the Map property `isEnabled` set to `false`.

Which is confusing because all the Map gestures work, but none of the binded XAML controls on top of it not.

Stupid mistake but nonetheless it might help people.